# Symfony2 raw query cast as entity

Tags: sql, symfony, pdo, doctrine-orm

I have a raw query in Symfony2

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Content
    JOIN ContentLearningAreas ON Content.id = ContentLearningAreas.content_id
    JOIN LearningArea ON ContentLearningAreas.learning_area_id = LearningArea.id
    WHERE ContentLearningAreas.learning_area_id = {$id} AND Content.active = 1";

$stmt = $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection()->prepare($sql);

$stmt->execute();

return $stmt->fetchAll();
```

This works fine, but I wish to cast the results to Content Entities so that their functions still work.

```
Jake\NameOfBundle\Entity\Content
```

How can this be done?

**EDIT**

It appears that this is using PDO and not Doctrine or Symfony2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works;

```
$stmt = $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection()->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$items = $stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_CLASS, "Jake\NameOfBundle\Entity\Content");
```

Comment: I'm doing the same thing but I have inheritance on a SINGLE TABLE. In each class I have an attribute name mapped on en_name or de_name etc. 
When I execute your code, it returns the right object but when I do $myObject->getName() it return null. Do you have an idea ?

Answer (score 1):

Please read about [Native Query](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html#native-sql) in doctrine 2.

> With NativeQuery you can execute native SELECT SQL statements and map
>   the results to Doctrine entities or any other result format supported
>   by Doctrine.

Comment: Thanks @forgottenbas, I did looked at this and dismissed it. For something seemingly so simple the time taken to understand & write the Native Query does not seem great. Perhaps its the only way......